# How to see queries executed in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I wonder if there is a way in SQL Server Management Studio to see the queries in T-SQL that have been executed in that background when we create or edit something using only the graphical interface .

For example if I click create database using the graphical interface, I want to see the code that have been executed to create the database, etc..

I tried to search but I didn't find anything

Comment: You can use the [profiler](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3502/how-to-launch-a-sql-server-profiler-session/) to see queries executed from an application. You can [script an existing table as CREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 3):

Most SSMS wizards have a "Script" button that will generate a script instead of performing the change directly.

[image]

Of course you can also use Profiler to capture all the traffic from a client, but it's not necessary to create scripts for common operations.